# PHP while loop adding 1 day to each date for 4 dates?

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop through and add cells to an HTML table, starting with a start date and adding one day to the start date with each iteration for 4 loops:

```
$DayCount = 0;

while ($DayCount < 5) {

echo "<td>";
echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+$DayCount days', strtotime($UpWeekStart)));
echo "</td>";

$DayCount = $DayCount + 1;

}
```

Is my syntax wrong? $UpWeekStart is a PHP variable containing user-selected date.

Comment: Yes. Escaping a string with single commas tells PHP it shouldn't reinterpret `$words` as variables. You have to use `"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"` instead of `'`:

```
echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+$DayCount days", strtotime($UpWeekStart)));
```

Single quoted strings will display things almost completely "as is." Variables and most escape sequences will not be interpreted. Whereas double quote strings will evaluate the variables in the string. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/1492578) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Remember your loop is starting at zero, and you are stopping it at 4 i.e. `< 5`, thats 5 iterations. Plus use double quotes around $variables you want expanded as in `strtotime("+$DayCount days", strtotime($UpWeekStart)`

So try

```
$DayCount = 0;

while ($DayCount < 4) {

    echo "<td>";
    echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+$DayCount days", strtotime($UpWeekStart)));
    echo "</td>";

    $DayCount = $DayCount + 1;

}
```